# Error while trying to edit Cortana channel

Tags: botframework, cortana-skills-kit

I am facing this error while trying to edit the Cortana channel in MS BOT.

It says that 'Sorry, something went wrong :-(' and the the trace id is: 7824e546-1332-419c-b4d3-9af2432a0ece

**Hint:** This error appeared after I have removed the user who created the bot from the subscription and added a new one instead.

[image: Sorry, something went wrong :-( Trace id: 7824e546-1332-419c-b4d3-9af2432a0ece]
Any idea how to fix this problem or how to delete the channel and create a new one? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Presently] the Cortana channel registration is owned by the developer that created it. Even though you can add other developers to work on the bot, the channel has one owner. Unfortunately the only thing you can do is, as you suggest, delete the channel and recreate it. If this doesn't work let me know via skillsup at microsoft dot com.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The delete button does not appear as usual. Is there any other way to delete the channel? Thanks.

Comment: Probably because the owner is gone.  Send the invocation name, bot id, and anything you have on the previous owner (i.e. email address) to the account mentioned and we'll look into it.

Comment: I got it.  Please delete the comment with the subscription id.

Comment: I deleted it :) Any news though?

Comment: Sent a confirmation email to the other registered account.  Waiting to hear back.

Comment: I did not receive anything in ls-utilites-bot@outlook.com inbox. Could you please tell to which email address you send the confirmation email?

Comment: I sent the email to an account with your name.  I'll see if I can proceed without.

Comment: Sorry but could not fine anything.. could you please send the email again and tell me which inbox I need to check? Thank you in advance.

Comment: send us an email with your primary email account to skillsup at microsoft dot com - helps me confirm your identity etc - thanks for your patience

Comment: I sent an email from ls-utilites-bot@outlook.com to the email address mentioned above. Thank you for checking.

Comment: We killed the channel.  Please recreate it.

Comment: Please check the mailbox, I replied to the last email. Thanks.